# CSS animation: make div float out of document

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I would like to create a CSS animation of clouds floating from left to right. I have a div with a width of 100% and the clouds are images with "position:absolute". My solution is pretty simple: create an animation, which changes the "left" property of the image over time to 120%. However, the problem with that solution is, that the clouds expand the width of the entire HTML document after crossing its full width.

How could I prevent that and make the clouds simply disappear to the right after crossing 100% of the width? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Here is a part of the CSS:

```
.header{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  height: 40em;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;

  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
 }

.cloud{
  position:absolute;
  left:-10%;
  animation: cloud 10s linear infinite;
 }


  @keyframes cloud{
  100%{
    left:150%;
  }
  }
```

Comment: `overflow: hidden` on your 100% width div. Also, don't animate on `left`. https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/

Comment: Your question should demonstrate your attempts..

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work. The same div is a flexbox, if that makes a difference. Also, what should I animate instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick example; use transform instead of left as it will use gpu acceleration if available. overflow-x is hidden on the body tag, to stop the scrollbar from appearing.

```css
body {
  min-width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  
}
.cloud {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  animation-name: cloud-animation;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-duration: 5s;
}

#cloud-2 {
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

#cloud-3 {
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

@keyframes cloud-animation {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(100vw);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="cloud-1" class="cloud"></div>
<div id="cloud-2" class="cloud"></div>
<div id="cloud-3" class="cloud"></div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! The "overflow-x" property was crucial! Thank you for your quick answer and advice!